# Unable to Import .obj file in expo three app

Tags: android, react-native, three.js, 3d, expo

I am attempting to import a .obj file from the assets folder in my expo application. I am getting the error:

```
Android Bundling failed 26225ms (D:\\Dev\\expo\\nook\\node_modules\\expo\\AppEntry.js)
Unable to resolve "missing-asset-registry-path" from "assets\\Suzanne.obj"
```

Here is the `metro.config.js` file that I am using to define the asset imports

```
const path = require('path');
const root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

module.exports = {
    projectRoot: __dirname,
    watchFolders: [root],

    resolver: {
      sourceExts: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'],
      assetExts: ['glb', 'gltf', 'mtl', 'obj', 'png', 'jpg'],
    },
  }
```

Here is my `App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLView } from "expo-gl";
import { Renderer } from "expo-three";
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GLView style={{ flex: 1 }} onContextCreate={this._onGLContextCreate} />
    );
  }
  _onGLContextCreate = async (gl) => {
    // 1. Scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    // 2. Camera
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      gl.drawingBufferWidth / gl.drawingBufferHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );
    // 3. Renderer
    const renderer = new Renderer({ gl });
    renderer.setSize(gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

    // Load object
    const objAsset = Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/Suzanne.obj'));
    await objAsset.downloadAsync();
    const uri = objAsset.localUri || objAsset.uri;

    const loader = new OBJLoader();
    loader.load(
      uri,
      (object) => {
        // Add the loaded object to your scene
        scene.add(object);
      },
      (xhr) => {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded');
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error loading OBJ file:', error);
      }
    );

    // const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    // const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    // const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    // scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.z = 5;
    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      gl.endFrameEXP();
    };
    animate();
  };
}
```

I have tried using this [`metro.config.js`](https://github.com/expo/expo-three/blob/master/example/metro.config.js) file as a reference from the example project in the main [expo-three](https://github.com/expo/expo-three/tree/master) repository, but cannot get it working. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).